African American captures Spanish president's assassination on film
I was watching a movie a while ago and forgot the movie title. It was about an African American who was touring Europe. He at a Spanish presidential ceremony when the president was assassinated. The African American caught the whole thing on tape. What movie is this?

Sounds like a single point of view from the movie Vantage Point, namely Forest Whittaker's part.

that was quick @TylerShads! You were done with the comment by the time I hunted for a picture to upload :P

Hah, was exactly what I thought when reading the question title.

Is it this? Vantage Point 
The plot is similar - 

U.S. President Henry Ashton (Hurt) attends a political summit in Salamanca, Spain to promote an international treaty. Displayed with eight differing viewpoints, an assassination attempt on the president occurs, relayed in a time span of 23 minutes.

